# Setting Print Margins in Layout so what you see is what you get

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, layouts

When I print my layouts in QGIS (my map, legend, etc) I get about 10mm added to the margins of the printed product (and yet the horizontal and vertical rulers are correct: i.e., 279mm x 216mm for US letter size).

This makes it difficult to balance my layout on the printed page. My work around has been to fiddle with extending all the map items, print it out, and then adjust. This is obviously not very time efficient.

Is there any way to set up the print layout window so that it shows what your map will look like once printed?

Comment: Just add the mergin of 10mm in your layout and draw inside it! No? And set your printer preferences with « no ajust » and 100%.

Comment: Are you printing the layout directly from QGIS or are you printing an exported layout such as a pdf?  When you measure your resulting layout print does the layout area match with the Map position and size settings or is it 10mm too small?  (Using a Frame for the test will make it easier to determine this if you don't have one.)  If it matches but your layout turns out to be offset, look at your reference point.